# How to do a transaction in mysqldb with truncate

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I am trying to truncate a table and then do some inserts and then commit it all at the end. However doing the following clears the table immediately:

```
>>> t.cursor.execute('START TRANSACTION;')
0L
>>> t.cursor.execute('TRUNCATE _tx;')
0L
# table is now cleared from truncate
```

How would I delay the 'truncate' until after I commit the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `TRUNCATE` within a transaction as it automatically commits. Better to do something like this:

```
>>> t.cursor.execute('DELETE FROM _tx;')
```

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant hey, no worries -- we're already connected (I've sent you a message already).